# "I give" in Isaiah 43:3

Tags: hebrew, isaiah

I came across this quite confusing construction in Isaiah 43:3. The ESV reads,

> For I am the LORD your God, the Holy One of Israel, your Savior. ***I give*** Egypt as your ransom, Cush and Seba in exchange for you.

The Hebrew is **נָתַתִּי** and parsed as Qal Perfect. Now the *perfect* is said to mean a completed event, whether it be past, present, or future. The ESV renders it in the present so I was quite confused about its time reference.

Some translations render it in the past,

> For I am the LORD thy God, The Holy One of Israel, thy Saviour; ***I have given*** Egypt as thy ransom, Ethiopia and Seba for thee. (JPS)

This brings interpretative issues. If the verse refers to a past event (Exodus), how does Cush (Ethiopia) and Seba fit in the picture? Also, it seems interpreters generally take the statement as referring to a futuristic Persian engagement.

Question: Is the past tense rendering of נָתַתִּי (Isa 43:3) in English translations wrong?

Comment: The next verse has וְאֶתֵּן אָדָם תַּחְתֶּיךָ (imperfect) apparently in reference to the same thing. I think the shift of aspect is just a poetic parallelism (and therefore not a great indicator of whether it refers to a specific event). Compare זָחַלְתִּי וָאִירָא (Job 32:6) "I feared (perfect) and I fear (imperfect)"

Comment: I think the shift to the imperfect in Job 32:6 is justified as זָחַלְתִּי refers to the past and אִירָא is a continuous attitude exhibited by the speaker, "afraid to declare".

Comment: My point was just that the shift of aspect is meant as poetic parallelism, and that I think Isaiah 43:3-4 is one such example. There are many other cases in the Bible, I can think of e.g. אֶחֱזֶה/רָאוּ (Job 19:27), עָלָה/תֹּאכֵל/בָּעֲרוּ (Psalms 18:9)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not wrong. The reason why Cush (Ethiopia) and Seba fit in the picture is, because their firstborn who were in Egypt while "Makot Bchorot" died too.
https://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta_d'Rabbi_Yishmael.12.29.1?vhe=Mekhilta_--_Wikisource&lang=bi